# How get makefile to find correct header for include with part of directory name

Tags: c++, makefile, header-files, include-path

I have a directory structure that looks like

AA/a.hpp

BB/Makefile

CC-CC/c.hpp

In the file a.hpp there's an include

```
#include "CC/c.hpp"
```

but the actual directory prefix is not CC it's "CC-CC". Is there a way to tell my Makefile, maybe through vpath or a wildcard somewhere, the "CC/c.hpp" that "AA/a.hpp" is looking for is actually "CC-CC/c.hpp"?

I can't rename the directory because it's part of a much larger work. The "AA/a.hpp" file is also not change-able for similar reasons. I know it's possible because there's another makefile with similar includes that got this scenario to work, albeit with some black magic auto-dependencies I can't seem to follow.

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: Using g++ as compiler.

Comment: Make a sim link to the cc-cc dir? (if it's coded as `#include "CC-CC/c.hpp"` I don't think there's a way to adjust the relative pathing from the make level.  For the AA dir you can just go: `-I../`

Comment: Why are they so messed up on the first place?

Comment: This is not possible. You need to change something in either the `#include` line or the file structure. The Makefile is irrelevant.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the "CC-CC" is meant as a prefix, it's actually more like "applicationB-CC" where CC originally applied to something else. I suppose the reasoning is new program, new file structure so it doesn't get confused with the original.

Comment: I agree with @melpomene, the include is at compile time, not way to adjust its relative pathing.  Add a sym-link from cc to cc-cc.

Comment: Thanks for the input, will go route of sym-link.